# Canvas Restore color

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

If you hover your mouse over the grid, squares will turn red. Now I'd like to have them change back to the original color(black) after 1sec using a fadeout effect. Can someone help?

I have tried something along the lines of ctx.restore but I guess I didn't implement it correctly as it did nothing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
  overflow:hidden;
      }
   
   #wrap {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
   }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#252525">
    <div class="wrap"><canvas id="canvas" width="5000" height="3000"></canvas></div>
    <script>
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    cw = 32,
    ch = 32,
    w = canvas.width,
    h = canvas.height;

ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5);
ctx.beginPath(); 

for(var y = 0; y < h; y += ch) {
 for(var x = 0; x < w; x += cw) {
      ctx.rect(x, y, cw-2, ch-2); // give 1px space  
  } 
}

ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";

ctx.lineWidth=1;
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();

canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {

  var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect(),
      x = e.clientX - rect.left,
      y = e.clientY - rect.top,
      cx = ((x / cw)|0) * cw, 
      cy = ((y / ch)|0) * ch;
  
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(cx+1, cy+1, cw-3, ch-3);
};
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you for any and all feedback!

Comment: You could after your fillRect use a timeOut https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout to revert back to the old color.

Comment: something like this ? http://jsbin.com/poqezohisi/1/edit?js,output

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot! Would you happen to know how to randomize the "red" color as well? Like get random colors, red, blue, green etc, instead of only red.

Comment: One more question. Sometimes the red squares don't fade out completely. Some of them remain 10% visible. Why does that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have your square fade out, you might use an interval that will regularly re-draw the rect with lower and lower opacity.
For each rect, you'll have to store some data : x, y, color, time when fade out started, and then the interval (so you can clear it to avoid the app getting slower and slower).
I bet you'll understand it all by reading the code but do not hesitate to ask.

(jsbin here : http://jsbin.com/gufikuwutu/1/edit
or code snippet below : )

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  cw = 32,
  ch = 32,
  w = canvas.width,
  h = canvas.height;

ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5);
ctx.beginPath();

for (var y = 0; y < h; y += ch) {
  for (var x = 0; x < w; x += cw) {
    ctx.rect(x, y, cw - 2, ch - 2); // give 1px space  
  }
}

ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";

ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();

var lastRect = null;

canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
  var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect(),
    x = e.clientX - rect.left,
    y = e.clientY - rect.top,
    cx = ((x / cw) | 0) * cw,
    cy = ((y / ch) | 0) * ch;

  // ignore this rect if we allready drawn it.
  if (lastRect && lastRect.cx == cx && lastRect.cy == cy) return;
  // pickup random color
  var randomHue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);
  var randomColor = 'hsl(' + randomHue + ', 85%, 60%)';
  ctx.fillStyle = randomColor;
  ctx.fillRect(cx + 1, cy + 1, cw - 3, ch - 3);
  // setup rect data
  var rectInfo = {
    cx: cx,
    cy: cy,
    t: Date.now(),
    color: randomColor,
    interval: 0
  };
  // setup interval
  rectInfo.interval = setInterval(fadeOutRect.bind(null, rectInfo), 30);
  lastRect = rectInfo;
};

function fadeOutRect(rectInfo) {
  var now = Date.now();
  var elapsed = now - rectInfo.t;
  var max = 1800;
  // clear the rect.
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
  ctx.fillRect(rectInfo.cx + 1, rectInfo.cy + 1, cw - 3, ch - 3);
  // exit if too much time elapsed.
  if (elapsed > max) {
    clearInterval(rectInfo.interval);
    return;
  }
  // draw the rect with an opacity proportionnal to time elapsed.
  ctx.save();
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1 - elapsed / max;
  ctx.fillStyle = rectInfo.color;
  ctx.fillRect(rectInfo.cx + 1, rectInfo.cy + 1, cw - 3, ch - 3);
  ctx.restore();
}
```

```css
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      #wrap {
        width: 600px;
        height: 600px;
      }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="5000" height="3000"></canvas>
</div>
```